# ¿Cómo saber si se actualiza un campo en el HTML?

Tags: javascript, contador, refresh

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función de `document` para saber mediante la consola del inspector del navegador si existe algún campo oculto que se está modificando constantemente en la página, por ejemplo un reloj (con los segundos) o un contador que se ejecuta cada `X` segundos (modifican continuamente el `text` de alguno de sus `tag`), una vez la página ya se ha terminado de cargar.

Por ejemplo, algo del estilo `document."isPageLoaded.isPageRefreshingEveryXSeconds"`.

A veces tenemos páginas que incluyen estos elementos ocultos y queremos detectar estos casos en un modo DEV para mandar un aviso a la consola y tratarlos como se deba en cada caso.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: y si usas el evento onchange?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. ¿Que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Se puede saber lo que hay en todo el documento *HTML* y pasarlo a *texto plano* haciendo un `outerHTML` a la primer etiqueta `html` que se encuentre.

```
document.querySelector("html").outerHTML
```

Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("html").outerHTML)
```

```html
Hola
```

La respuesta que me da *este snippet* es:

```
<html><head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    Hola
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.querySelector("html").outerHTML)
    </script></body></html>
```

Sabiendo esto, se puede agregar cada tanto tiempo el resultado del texto plano a un array. Para saber si cambió al menos en una mínima cosa, se puede comparar si los *strings (los textos planos)* son iguales.

```js
window.registros_html = []
setInterval(function(){
  var a = document.createElement("a")
  a.innerHTML = " Hola."
  document.body.appendChild(a)}
  ,2020)

setInterval(function(){
  window.registros_html.push( document.querySelector("html").outerHTML )
  if(window.registros_html.length>=2){
    var último = window.registros_html[window.registros_html.length-1]
    var penúltimo = window.registros_html[window.registros_html.length-2]
    var son_iguales = (penúltimo==último)
    console.log( "¿Son iguales?", son_iguales )
  }
},1000)
```

```html
Hola.
```

Nota: En este caso siempre dará `false` (nunca serán iguales), ya que se está cambiando la consola, que viene integrada al *snippet*.

Dicho esto, tendrás que ingeniarte para crear un complejo sistema que detecte cambios en el *string* y así poder analizar la parte que se desea, quizás mediante expresiones regulares.

Answer (score -1):

Según https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp puedes hacer algo como

```
document.getElementById().onchange
```

para detectar todos los elementos de la página puedes añadirles una clase y luego haces

```
document.getElementByClass().onchange
```

y luego ya filtras por contadores o número de cambios o como quieras

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, el `change` solo detecta los cambios en el atributo `value` y no en los otros atributos como se pide en la pregunta, y tampoco detecta en los campos `hidden` que es lo que supongo que se refiere el OP con _campos ocultos_.. Ademas de que deberíamos dejar al OP primero mostrar lo que ha intentando

Comment: creo que busca un método o función directo que NO hay conforme al enlace que he aportado. Lo más cercano es hacer algo de este estilo, jugar con eventos, pero no hay nada directo hay que ir navegando a través de documento. Entiendo que la pregunta no se refiere a como se hace esto, sino si existe algo que lo haga directo, a lo que la respuesta es no, es como tener una string y buscar una subcadena y reemplazarla por otra, y preguntar si algo lo puede hacer directamente, respuesta Replace, pero NO en este caso

Comment: De paso, mira [esto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280484/73749) para ver que es mejor linkear la documentacion oficial, y no w3schools